# Angular, sharing row in two components

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to share same row between components? Currently side navbar takes 2 columns and I wish to each card take exactly 3. This is how it looks now:
[image]

And I expect this:

[image]

main.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <admin-navbar></admin-navbar>
    </div>
    <admin-cards></admin-cards>
  </div>
</div>
```

navbar.html:

```
<div id="sidenav" class="navbar-fixed-left">
  <a routerLink="product" class="list-group-item">
      <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      <span class="hidden-sm-down">Produkty</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
        <span class="hidden-sm-down">Kategorie</span>
   </a>
  <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar">
  <span class="hidden-sm-down">Zamówienia     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
</a>
  <div class="collapse" id="menu3">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu2sub1">W trakcie realizacji</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu2sub1">Zrealizowane</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu2sub1">Twoje zamówienia</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

cards.html:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card text-white h-100 text-center">
      <div class="card-body bg-success">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
        <h6>Zamówienia</h6>
        <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card text-white h-100 text-center">
      <div class="card-body bg-info">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
        <h6>Wiadomości</h6>
        <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card text-white h-100 text-center">
      <div class="card-body bg-warning">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
        <h6>Spotkania</h6>
        <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like, classes inside components doesn't affects outer components. On expected screen I just put everything into main.html, but the goal is to iterate over cards using *ngFor on displaying, another reason is to separate navbar and cards in different modules.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz to reproduce please? It'll be much easier for people to debug. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your `card`s in a `card-group`,you should get the behavior you want.

```
<div class="card-group col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card text-white h-100 text-center">
        <div class="card-body bg-success">
          <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
          <h6>Zamówienia</h6>
          <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card text-white h-100 text-center">
        <div class="card-body bg-info">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
          <h6>Wiadomości</h6>
          <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card text-white h-100 text-center">
        <div class="card-body bg-warning">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i>
          <h6>Spotkania</h6>
          <h1 class="display-4">134</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a StackBlitz to demonstrate:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzzbwx?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is solution you're looking for, but since the columns need to be defined at the same level. What about iterating over a single card:

main.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <admin-navbar></admin-navbar>
    </div>
    <admin-card *ngFor="let card of cards" [data]="card" class="col-md-3"></admin-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what  for `[data]` is responsible here?

Comment: The idea was that your AdminCardComponent is reusable and has   `@Input() data;` defined where you pass in the card's JSON data from the ngFor loop.

Comment: got it, thanks for clarify, I will stay with @user184994 answer to keep separating of components